# « Le Lactume » et la trilogie originale de Réjean Ducharme : chronologie et identité ?

Tags: québec, littérature, style-de-rédaction, jeux-de-mots

[Réjean Ducharme](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A9jean_Ducharme) (1941-[2017](http://www.newswire.ca/fr/news-releases/les-editions-gallimard-ont-la-tristesse-de-faire-part-du-deces-le-21-aout-2017-dans-sa-soixante-dix-septieme-annee-de-m-rejean-ducharme-ecrivain-641410733.html)), écrivain, dramaturge, scénariste et sculpteur québécois, [n'est plus](http://www.ledevoir.com/culture/actualites-culturelles/506250/rejean-ducharme-1941-2017-mort-d-un-immense-fantome). Alors qu'il était âgé de 24 ans, on avait refusé de publier un de ses manuscrits de sorte qu'il s'était tourné du côté de chez Gallimard en leur en soumettant trois, dont [*L'Avalée des avalés*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27Aval%C3%A9e_des_aval%C3%A9s), qu'ils publièrent en 1966 et qui fut en lice pour le Goncourt. On publia par la suite [*Le Nez qui voque*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Nez_qui_voque) (1967) et [*L'Océantume*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27Oc%C3%A9antume) (1968) dont l'article Wikipédia dit du titre qu'il « est un jeu de mot à partir d'"amertume", où océan remplace "mer" ».

L'ordre de publication diffère cependant de l'ordre de composition de ces œuvres. Dans un article, ["Réjean Ducharme : du mythe au roman"](https://www.erudit.org/fr/revues/vi/1993-v18-n3-vi1353/201053ar.pdf), *Voix et Images*, vol. XVIII, no 3 (54), printemps 1993, Nicole Bourbonnais indique (à la p. 594) que l'ordre de composition, confirmé par l'auteur (à la p. 597, note 5), est tout d'abord *L'Océantume*, suivi de *L'Avalée des avalés*, puis enfin *Le Nez qui voque*. Il s'agit d'une discussion de l'essai de Franca Marcato-Falzoni, *Du mythe au roman, une trilogie ducharmienne* (traduit de  l'italien  par Javier  Garcia  Méndez), Montréal, *VLB éditeur*, 1992, dont elle dit de l'auteure qu'elle « a le grand mérite d'établir clairement le fil conducteur de la trilogie et de mettre en lumière les liens aussi bien formels que sémantiques qui unissent  les trois romans. ».

---

Or on [apprend](http://www.ledevoir.com/culture/livres/506307/l-ouvrage-posthume-le-lactume-de-rejean-ducharme-en-librairie-vendredi) que *Les Éditions du Passage* viennent de publier *Le Lactume*, œuvre inédite de l'auteur, de 1966, un « recueil de 198 dessins et légendes ». On remarque que le titre utilise le même procédé que dans *L'Océantume*, cette fois-ci avec le nom « lac ». On aimerait généralement situer cette œuvre dans le patrimoine de l'auteur en littérature de langue française et savoir quel éclairage elle y apporte, dans un contexte moderne où l'on s'attarde davantage à la genèse de la création littéraire.

---

- La composition du *Lactume* précède-t-elle ou suit-elle chronologiquement celle de *L'Océantume* (ou d'une autre des trois oeuvres) ?
- Existe-t-il un lien particulier entre *Le Lactume* et *L'Océantume*, au-delà d'un titre/néologisme/jeu de mots le suggérant ; le titre suffirait-il à l'établir ; est-ce que ça relèverait d'un même style de rédaction ?
- Plus généralement, *Le Lactume* participe-t-il des « liens formels et
  sémantiques » de la trilogie (quadrilogie) en question (ou plus généralement des [thèmes](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A9jean_Ducharme#Th.C3.A8mes_abord.C3.A9s) chers à l'auteur, ou autrement) ?

Comment: Je me suis demandé si la question ne devait pas plutôt se trouver sur le site Literature mais je n'en suis pas [convaincu](https://literature.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Même si l'oeuvre de l'auteur a été primée, ça provient d'un coin de la francophonie et comme il n'y a aucun article Wikipédia là-dessus, j'ai pensé qu'il y avait plus de chance que des francophones aient de l'information sur le sujet. Il ne s'agit pas d'une question technique mais néanmoins, il s'agit d'une oeuvre importante (pour moi du moins). On ne sait pas si ça passe la barre. On verra. Merci !

Comment: Peu de choses à en dire: si j'ai aimé *L'avalée des avalées*, j'ai eu plus de difficulté avec *Le nez qui voque* et n'ai pas lu *L'Océantume*. À la lumière de votre explication de l'étymologie de *L'Océantume*, je me dis que l'eau de mer est salée et amère, et que l'eau des lacs étant (le plus souvent) douce, peut-être *Le Lactume* est-il destiné à être l'antithèse, la version douce de *L'Océantume*, une mot fabriqué qui serve en quelque sorte d'antonyme à *amertume*. Tout ceci demeure strictement spéculatif, bien sûr, puisque je n'ai lu ni l'un ni l'autre.

Comment: Le précédent commentaire soumis néanmoins avec une certaine expérience de l'œuvre de Ducharme, qui m'a semblé en général assez triste et désillusionnée. Peut-être d'autres y auront-ils davantage perçu l'impressionnant et exquis travail linguistique de l'écrivain.

Comment: @Feelew Merci ! Ma connaissance de l'artiste et de son œuvre se résume à l'article Wikipédia. Parfois on veut découvrir une œuvre sans que notre regard ne soit teinté par celui des autres. Parfois, et c'est le cas pour moi ici, je veux aborder une œuvre ou un ensemble d’œuvres par l'analyse et la genèse de la création (ou des variantes postérieures, comme ds. Nelligan _Oeuvres complètes II_, Poèmes et textes d'asile). Et je veux voir ces dessins avant de lire quoi que ce soit. La discussion sur l'étendue d'eau au titre participe du tout; sa qualité, et, à l'évidence, son envergure...