# Équivalent Oulipo en Suisse ? Belgique ? Canada ?

Tags: québec, belgique, jeux-de-mots, suisse

Bonjour !

Je connais Devos, Desproges, Perec, Prévert, Queneau, etc... 
L'Oulipo et autre Papous dans la tête...

Question : quels sont les équivalents chez les autres francophones, en particulier en Suisse française, Belgique et Québec ? Des écrivains et des auteurs, leurs livres, des humoristes ou des associations qui se spécialisent ou qui sont connus pour leurs jeux de mots ? (en français)

Answer (score 5):

Plus généralement, au Québec, de manière populaire, à mon avis [François Pérusse](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fran%C3%A7ois_P%C3%A9russe) est un incontournable pour ses [sketches radiophoniques](https://www.youtube.com/user/LeFrancoisPerusse/featured), en particulier ses fameuses *2 minutes du peuple*. On ne saurait passer sous silence aussi l'auteur et comédien [Claude Meunier](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Claude_Meunier) (*La petite vie*, *Les voisins*, Ding et Dong - avec [Serge Thériault](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serge_Th%C3%A9riault)). Plusieurs groupes d'humoristes ont fait dans l'absurde il y a un moment déjà, dont, évidemment, [*Rock et Belles Oreilles*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rock_et_Belles_Oreilles) ([Refelemele](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yTtehX54DYQ), [Bonjour la police](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pEx5ovtkivo), [Ça rend rap](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kLobSbGAf28) etc.), [*Les Chick'n Swell*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Les_Chick%27n_Swell), les [*Bleu Poudre*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Les_Bleu_Poudre) et le phénomène Internet les [Têtes à claques](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/T%C3%AAtes_%C3%A0_claques). Côté littérature, et d'autres s'y connaîtront davantage, sans parler d'humoriste comme tel, un sait que [Réjean Ducharme](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A9jean_Ducharme) (*L'avalée des avalés*, [etc](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/26995/le-lactume-et-la-trilogie-originale-de-r%C3%A9jean-ducharme-chronologie-et-iden).) était connu pour son « recours fréquent aux jeux de mots, aux néologismes et aux inventions de langage » (Wikipédia). On peut aussi jeter un coup d'oeil à l'article [*Humour québécois*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humour_qu%C3%A9b%C3%A9cois) sur Wikipédia pour quelques liens, la référence au [Gala Les Oliviers](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gala_Les_Olivier) « honorant l'excellence de l'humour québécois » (en référence à [Olivier Guimond](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olivier_Guimond), un grand pionnier du burlesque au Québec), une [analyse](https://carleton.ca/profbrouard/wp-content/uploads/RapportProfilIndustriehumourQuebec201501.pdf) économique et une [liste](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_des_humoristes_qu%C3%A9b%C3%A9cois) d'humoristes québécois(es), dont [Marc Favreau](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marc_Favreau) (personnage de *Sol*, [ex. de monologue](https://youtu.be/qYJq_Knt254)) :

> Si tous les poètes voulaient se donner la main, ils toucheraient enfin
>   des doigts d’auteur ! 
>    Nous avons envers elle une conduite imbuvable ! [au sujet de la préservation  de l'eau]
>   [ Sol, Marc Favreau ]

Answer (score 4):

En Belgique, quelques humoristes se sont faits connaître pour leurs textes truffés de jeux de mots. Certains (les meilleurs?) ont fait carrière en France.
Parmi les humoristes actuels, dont vous pourrez trouver certainement les chroniques ou extraits de spectacles sur le web, il y a:

-Stéphane De Groodt (également connu en France)

-Bruno Coppens

-Jérôme de Warzée (il est surtout connu pour animer et écrire les textes d'une émission satirique hebdomadaire à la télévision belge, mais je pense qu'il y aborde surtout des sujets "belgo-belges" incompréhensibles à l'étranger. Regardez plutôt des extraits de ses one-man shows.)

Plus dans un genre "chansonnier"comme Bobby Lapointe, le groupe "Sttellla" (en fait un seul homme: Jean-Luc Fonck) s'est spécialisé dans les chansons prétextes à calembours et jeux de mots.

Enfin, de par ses origines, Raymond Devos est considéré comme belge par tous les Belges amateurs de jeux de mots, même si au sens strict, il avait la nationalité française...